# Post data to MySQL DB using Axios-REACT API via spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I have several values in the frontend and am using useState Hook to update them. All seem to do fine including the Bmi value at least on the front end. But when I post them, all go well except that at the first submit, I get 0 (initial state value of bmi) instead of the computed value.

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Below are some snippets of my code:

```
 const [bmi, setBmi] = useState('0');
```

const client = axios.create({
baseURL: "https://localhost:8080/patient/addPatient"
});

const addPosts = (pName,pAge,pSex,pWeight,pHeight,pBMI) => {
client
.post('http://localhost:8080/patient/addPatient', {
name: pName,
age: pAge,
sex: pSex,
weight: pWeight,
height: pHeight,
bmi: pBMI
})
.then((response) => {
setPosts([response.data, ...posts]);
});

};

I compute the BMI value like so:

```
let bmi_val = (weight / (height * height)).toFixed(1);
```

And compare it for different ranges to give the right message.

```
let handleClick={    
        
        (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (weight === 0 || height === 0) {
            alert("Enter valid values, please. ")
            setImgUrl('');
          } else {
            // update all the  values
            setName(name)
            setSex(sex) 
            setAge(age)
            setWeight(weight)
            setHeight(height)

            let bmi_val = (weight / (height * height)).toFixed(1);
            
            // console.log(`bmi is ${bmi}`); // for testing
            
            if (bmi_val <= 18.5) {
              setMessage("You are underweight")
              setImgUrl(underweight)  
              setBmi(bmi_val)

            } else if (bmi_val > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
              setMessage("You have normal weight")
              setImgUrl(normalweight)
              setBmi(bmi_val)

            } else if (bmi_val >= 25.0 && bmi < 29.9) {
              setMessage("You are overweight")
              setImgUrl(overweight)
              setBmi(bmi_val)

            } else if(bmi_val >= 30.0){
              setMessage("You are obese")
              setImgUrl(obese)
              setBmi(bmi_val)
            }
            
               
            
          }
          // setBmi(bmi_val);
          
          
          addPosts(name, age, sex, weight, height, bmi); // posts data to the database
          
        }           
          
      }`code here
```

the handleClick() method is a prop to a child component. In the child I call is to compute the bmi and also give the appropriate message and also post to the db using the addPosts() method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)